# WooCommerce shop currency by user role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles

I would like to switch the currency of my wordpress/woocommerce shop to USD when the logged in user name contains the array "usd".

I tried with this code but it didn't work. Could you please help me?

Thank you

```
function set_role_currency($currency){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 $user = wp_get_current_user();
 $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;}
 if (in_array('usd', $roles)) { return 'USD'; }
 return $currency; 
}
add_filter('woocommerce_currency', 'set_role_currency', 10, 2);
```

Comment: "user name contains the array "usd"" ? Does it mean that your username contains the word "usd" like this: "username_usd" or do you set any roles for the user as "usd"?

Comment: the user role contains "usd", how to double check whether the role wordpress is comparing against really contains the string "usd"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe all you need is just to fix this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency', 'set_role_currency', 10, 2);
```

Since you are passing only 1 param, and maybe set the priority to be later:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency', 'set_role_currency', 100, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks you for your quick response. 
I think that the issue is in finding the string "usd" in the user role array. I created the additional user role with the plugin WooCommerce Wholesale Pro and I called it "wholesale_usd". I think that the display name is "wholesale_usd" but the real name behind it is different. How can I check the name of the user role?

Comment: @Ahmed you can always use built-in WC loggers. 
$logger = new WC_Logger();
 $logger_name = "My Logger Name";
 $logger->add($logger_name,print_r($user->roles, true));